# Run a script in Maya by right clicking UI?

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I'm fairly new to python, and I am trying to run the code I wrote when I right click the playback range windows in the timeline of maya (where you type your min or max range) . I managed to find ways to run scripts within the attribute editor / timeline / shelf items, but I cant seem to figure out how to interact with Maya's UI... Even typing a new value in there doesn't update the script editor, so I don't really have a lead on where to go. Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

you basically want to add a menu item in the timeslider ?. You can get all maya widget using OpenMayaUI.MQtUtil and here is a full repo which modify timeline control https://github.com/robertjoosten/maya-timeline-marker

Answer (score 0):

Everything Maya does when using the UI logs data in the script editor.

Many items in the log are suppressed though as it would spam the log.
To enable it, activate `Echo all commands` (can be found in script editor under `History`), then clear the script editor and perform the action you want logged.

You will find that Maya executes a lot of mel script functions, which you can all find in the maya install directory under `[MAYA_INSTALL_DIR]/scripts/startup` and `[MAYA_INSTALL_DIR]/scripts/others`

To find the essential function you will have to search a little through the log.
Once you got a mel function you want to look for, I recommend using a `find in files` search function like the one in `Notepad++`, to find the corresponding .mel file in which the `global proc` is defined.

Also note that UI element names that are logged in script editor may have a different name the next time you start maya. So you will have to add functionality to search for the correct UI element name.

The Maya mel scripts are a good resource to find out all sorts of things about how the UI works, including contextual marking menus and the commands of tool windows.